# Как изменить размер таблицы в Qt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, layout

Как сделать, чтобы талица не растягивалась на весь корневой виджет?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QWidget()
    table = QTableWidget()
    table.setGeometry(0,0,100,100)
    table.setColumnCount(2)
    table.setRowCount(3)
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Парам.', 'Знач.'])
    parameters = ['Min', 'Max', 'Average']
    i = 0
    for p in parameters:
        table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(p))
        i += 1
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(table)
    mainWindow.setLayout(vbox)
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('App')
    mainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 800)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

На картинке, черной рамкой указал то, как какие размеры должна была занимать таблица в корневом виджете.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пишите: `Как сделать, чтобы талица не растягивалась на весь корневой виджет?` . Прикрепите пожалуйста изображение как сейчас растягивается таблица.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил картинку.

Comment: у меня при запуске вашего примера так и получается! Уточните пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы кладете что-то в `Q*Layout`, то доверяете компоновщику располагать и изменять размер виджета, а т.к. у вас только одна таблица была добавлена, то она заняла весь доступный размер.

Но ее можно ограничить.

Попробуйте использовать метод [setFixedSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1), например вместо:

```
table.setGeometry(0,0,100,100)
```

укажите:

```
table.setFixedSize(100, 100)
```

---

**PS.**

Еще есть методы [setMinimumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMinimumSize-1), [setMaximumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMaximumSize-1). А так же методы для фиксации размеров чисто для ширины или высоты, например [setMinimumWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumWidth-prop) и [setMinimumHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения.